# Thread started <Thread Pool> : When i get data from api

Tags: c#, multithreading, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to get data from api and put to group listview, but app not show error and not display data. Sorry my english not good

**This my function to download data:**

```
public async Task<List<GroupInvoiceInList>> test_connection()
    {
        var listItems = new List<GroupInvoiceInList> ();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("token","40df006e4c4314aefd892e335a743338c8d3331e");

                var response = await client.GetAsync(SuperVAR.URL_CUSTOMER_GET_LISTINVOICE+"?limit=15");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    JObject res = JObject.Parse (response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ().Result);
                    string message = res ["message"].ToString ();
                    if (message.Equals ("Success")) {
                        JArray arrayData = (JArray)res["data"]["invoiceList"];
                        GroupInvoiceInList g1 = new GroupInvoiceInList (1437880499);
                        for (int i = 0; i < arrayData.Count; i++) {
                            var item = (JObject)arrayData [i];

                            InvoiceInList hihi = new InvoiceInList (Int32.Parse(item["invoiceStatus"].ToString()));
                            hihi.invoiceId = Int32.Parse(item["invoiceId"].ToString());
                            hihi.invoiceProductName = item["productName"].ToString();
                            hihi.contactPhone = item["receiverPhone"].ToString();
                            hihi.invoiceReceiverName = item["receiverName"].ToString();
                            hihi.invoiceReceiverAddress = item["receiverFullAddress"].ToString();
                            hihi.invoiceCodFee = Double.Parse(item["codFee"].ToString());
                            hihi.invoiceSumFee = Double.Parse(item["sumFee"].ToString());
                            g1.Add (hihi);

                            Debug.WriteLine(hihi.invoiceId+"");
                        }
                        listItems.Add (g1);

                    } else {
                        //DisplayAlert ("", message, "OK");
                    }
                }
            }
        return listItems;
    }
```

and code to display in layout

```
var listItems = test_connection ().Result;
listView = new ListView 
    {
        SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,
        HasUnevenRows = true,
        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(InvoiceInListCell)),
        IsGroupingEnabled = true,
        GroupHeaderTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(GroupInvoiceInListCell)),
        ItemsSource = listItems
    };
this.Content = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {listView  },
        BackgroundColor = Color.White,
    };
```

DataModel: 
**GroupInvoiceInList**

```
public class GroupInvoiceInList : ObservableCollection<InvoiceInList>
    {
        public int dayOfMonth { get; set;}
        public string dayOfWeek { get; set; }
        public string monthAndYear { get; set;}

        public GroupInvoiceInList (long time)
            {
                DateTime timeA = SuperFUNC.FromUnixTime(time);
                this.dayOfMonth = timeA.Day;
                this.dayOfWeek = SuperFUNC.ConvertToDayOfWeek ((int)timeA.DayOfWeek);
                this.monthAndYear = SuperFUNC.ConvertToMonthOfYear ((int)timeA.Month) + " " + timeA.Year;
            }
    }
```

**InvoiceInList**

```
public class InvoiceInList
    {
        public int invoiceId{ set; get;}
        public string invoiceStatus{ set; get;}
        public string contactPhone{ set; get;}
        public string invoiceProductName { set; get;}
        public string invoiceReceiverName { set; get;}
        public string invoiceReceiverAddress { set; get;}
        public double invoiceCodFee{ set; get;}
        public double invoiceSumFee{ set; get;}
        public long invoiceCreateDate{ set; get;}
        public Color backGroundTop { set; get;} 

        public InvoiceInList (int invoiceStatus)
            {
                this.invoiceStatus = SuperFUNC.ConvertStatusToString (invoiceStatus);
                this.backGroundTop = SuperFUNC.ConvertStatusToColor (invoiceStatus);
            }
    }
```

Application Output:

```
 Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
    Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
```

I'm a newbie of c# and xamarin, thank for read

Comment: is your `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` `true`? if so what are you getting in `return listItems;` - does in contains any items?

Comment: @MilenPavlov: yes, i has tried Debug.WriteLine(hihi.invoiceId+""); in loop block and it working .. response.IsSuccessStatusCode true

Comment: Could be an UI issue then, also it's recommended to use `await` instead of `.Result` like `var listItems = await test_connection ();`

Comment: @MilenPavlov: await  can't use in default contructor function

Comment: `Task.Run(async () => await test_connection());`

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be an issue with running the json connection on the same thread as the UI interaction so therefore without an await the listview is updated before the data is returned.

I used single responsibility in my code and used an event handler to detect when the data set had changed to rebind the data on the listview. My example is XMl but the concept is the same.

Reference to Listview Data Binding:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Customizing_the_Appearance_of_a_Cell

Called on Page OnAppearing Event

```
var response = await DataHelper.GetData();
```

HTTP Request in my Data Helper Class

```
 public static async Task<string> GetData()
        {
    var result = true;
    var url = "API Call URL";

    var content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    content["needed parameter for API call"] = ID;
    var response = await WebRequestHelper.MakeAsyncRequest(url, content);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
    result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    result = result.Replace("<xml>", "<ModelResultName>").Replace("</xml>", "</ModelResultName>");
                }
                else
                {
                    result = false;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Failed to get data");
                }
return result;
```

I then have an event handler to detect the change and rebind my Listview Data Source

```
    public event EventHandler<ModelName> ResultUpdated;

    private void ResultUpdated(object sender, GamesResult e)
    {
            Model "In your case InvoiceInList" itemSource = null;
            ListView.ItemsSource = itemSource;        
    }
```

Also note that your listview ItemTemplate should bind to your data template bindings on your model for example:

```
ListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(InvoiceInListCell))

Label invoiceProductName = new Label();
invoiceProductName .SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "productName");
```